# About database and content provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What's the difference between sqlite database and content provider in android and what scenario we employ both of them in our app.

Comment: Read documentation for it.

Comment: They both give data, and the main difference is that content provider can be use to share data across applications.

Comment: I need a real time example bro

Comment: You can get plenty of real time examples by a simple google search. Try http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both sqlite database and content provider in apps like contacts/phone dialer application.

Sqlite can be used to store all the contact details in record formats. And the same set of contacts can be provided to other apps through content providers.